# Change TextField Display with RadioButton

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic, gridpane

I'm having a problem with Label and TextField placement in a gridpane in response to toggled RadioButtons.

The window will display the same options except for two different labels and text fields which depend on which RadioButton the user has selected.(See images attached).

[InHouse RB Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrjmp.jpg)
[Outsourced RB Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae9Lc.jpg)

I added the RadioButton objects to a Toggle Group, then coded the "on actions" to add the "Machine ID" or "Company Name" fields to the GridPane as needed when one of the options is selected.

My problem is that I can only select each option once, and the display of the second option only overlaps the first instance instead of replacing it. If I try to switch back again, I get a runtime error(in Netbeans) about adding the same object twice to the grid.

Any code that I have tried that could remove the node from the display had no affect on the menu's behavior.

```
    ArrayList<Label> typeSpecLabels = new ArrayList<Label>();
    ArrayList<TextField>typeSpecFields = new ArrayList<TextField>();

    typeSpecLabels.add(machineIDLabel);
    typeSpecLabels.add(companyLabel);

    typeSpecFields.add(machineIDField);
    typeSpecFields.add(companyNameField);

    inHouseBtn.setOnAction(inHouseSpecificEvent ->
    { 
        typeSpecLabels.add(machineIDLabel);

        grid1.add(typeSpecLabels.get(0),0,8,1,1);
        grid1.add(typeSpecFields.get(0), 1,8,1,1);


        if(outSourceBtn.isArmed() == true){
            grid1.getChildren().remove(companyLabel);
            grid1.getChildren().remove(companyNameField);
        }
    });


    outSourceBtn.setOnAction(outSourceSpecificEvent ->
    {
        typeSpecLabels.add(companyLabel);
        grid1.add(companyLabel,0,8,1,1);
        grid1.add(companyNameField,1,8,1,1);

        if(outSourceBtn.isArmed() == true){
            grid1.getChildren().remove(machineIDLabel);
            grid1.getChildren().remove(machineIDField);
        }
    });
```

I have heard that I could try using 2 or 3 different scenes(one for each state of the RadioButtons), so I may try that. But if it can be done the way I have coded it so far, I would prefer to do it that way.

Comment: Why add and remove from the scene - couldn't you make visible/invisible?

Comment: That would solve the overlapping problem, but I would still have the issue that the gui doesn't respond if I reselect a button that I have already chosen before.

Based on the runtime error, I figured I would need to remove the node from the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ended up working, as Pavlo suggested. 
Although I just removed the objects specific to the opposing event.
The code works with no errors or overlapping.

```
        inHouseBtn.setOnAction(inHouseSpecificEvent ->
    {

        grid1.add(machineIDLabel,0,8,1,1);
        grid1.add(machineIDField,1,8,1,1);

        grid1.getChildren().remove(companyLabel);
        grid1.getChildren().remove(companyNameField);
    });


    outSourceBtn.setOnAction(outSourceSpecificEvent ->
    {

        grid1.add(companyLabel,0,8,1,1);
        grid1.add(companyNameField,1,8,1,1);

        grid1.getChildren().remove(machineIDLabel);
        grid1.getChildren().remove(machineIDField);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove all *type specific labels and fields* from your grid and then add ones that you need. So the code will look like following:

```
inHouseBtn.setOnAction(inHouseSpecificEvent ->
{ 
    grid1.getChildren().removeAll(machineIDLabel, companyLabel, machineIDField, companyNameField);

    grid1.add(machineIDLabel,0,8,1,1);
    grid1.add(machineIDField, 1,8,1,1);
});


outSourceBtn.setOnAction(outSourceSpecificEvent ->
{
    grid1.getChildren().removeAll(machineIDLabel, companyLabel, machineIDField, companyNameField);

    grid1.add(companyLabel,0,8,1,1);
    grid1.add(companyNameField,1,8,1,1);
});
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines when I added the items to the ArrayLists since they can add/remove elements on demand.

I'll try it the way you suggested and see what I get.